# HP Procurve 3500 with K.14 - strange MAC search issue

Tags: hp, hp-procurve, mac-address

I have strange issue with HP ProCurve J8692A 3500yl-24G.
If I display MACs on port I see it:

```
3500(config)# sh mac 10 | inc 5cf3fc-a53456
5cf3fc-a53456
```

But if I try to find where is this MAC then I have no luck:

```
(config)# sh mac 5cf3fc-a53456
 Status and Counters - Address Table - 5cf3fc-a53456 
MAC address 5cf3fc-a53456 not found.
```

Any ideas where can be the problem?

Edited:
I test another MAC:

```
3500# sh mac 003048-33d8f6

 Status and Counters - Address Table - 003048-33d8f6

MAC address 003048-33d8f6 not found.
3500# sh mac | inc 003048-33d8f6
  003048-33d8f6 5
3500#
```

so this not looks as MAC, config mode or port issue.
Also:

```
MAC addr count#                1241       1257       1248       1449       1391
                     Low          *          *       1229       1222       1219
                    High          *          *       1266       1897       1897
```

and this switch have much larger (AFAIR 64k) MAC address table size, so it not looks like full MAC address table issue.

PS.
It run on bit old K.14.41 software. I check [Release notes](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.BINARYPORTLET/public/kb/docDisplay/resource.process/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay_ws_BI&spf_p.rid_kbDocDisplay=docDisplayResURL&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&spf_p.rst_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-resourceState=docId%253Demr_na-c03790791-1%257CdocLocale%253D&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) for K.14 series, but I don't see similar problem resolved in any next release.

Comment: Well the OID suggests its an IBM device. The documentation suggests you are supposed to see the port number that this address is learned on. While I doubt this can be a switch system address, perhaps including the entire output of the sho mac 10, also just for grins try the commands not in config mode

Comment: @fredpbaker I edited post and added more information. I not post full output of `sh mac 10` because it's rather long - I have another switch on this port :)

Comment: So what I see is that a normal mac address entry as a port number in it per the doc. The IBM address does not. The sho mac <address> command seems to never work. This smells like code defects

Comment: @fredpbaker, the IBM address doesn't show a port number because that is a "sh mac <interface> | inc <MAC>" whereas the second is from a "show mac | inc <MAC>".  Since the first includes the interface with the input, there is no reason to include it in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade to the K.15 series. I also have a 3500yl-48G, and prior to K.15 I definitely saw bugs.

`sh mac-a` never worked properly for me in K.14, but does in K.15.

```
HP-3500yl-48G# sh mac-address 46           

 Status and Counters - Port Address Table - 46

  MAC Address   VLANs       
  ------------- ------------
  00005e-00010a 100         
  00005e-000201 100         
  00005e-000202 100         
  002283-f8dff0 100         
  f8c001-c56208 100         

HP-3500yl-48G# sh mac-address 46 |inc 00005e-00010a
 00005e-00010a 100         
HP-3500yl-48G# sh mac-address 00005e-00010a | inc 46
 46       100 

HP-3500yl-48G# sh version 
Image stamp:    /ws/swbuildm/rel_knoxville_qaoff/code/build/btm(swbuildm_rel_knoxville_qaoff_rel_knoxville)
                Feb 28 2013 11:40:02
                K.15.12.0006
                639
Boot Image:     Secondary
```

Comment: This is a borderline "+1" comment, but I want to reinforce robbat2's comment about K.14.*  K.14.* was really buggy in a lot of ways.  You will certainly do yourself numerous favors by getting off of it and go ahead and getting up to K.15.*  Not that K.15.* is perfect by any means, but its tremendously better.